# Python theleton add text to message

Tags: python, telethon

I have such a code:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=ID))
async def handler_new_message(event):
    try:
        await client.send_message(ID, event.message)
        print('Сообщение:',event.message)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

How can I add my text to the message body?
To be for example so

> My text: Message that I got from another channel

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `await client.send_message(ID, f'My text: {event.message}')`?

Comment: Almost, but then I see an array but not a message.https://prnt.sc/1xmyf2b

Comment: you have object `message` with many different informations - and you have to get text from this object. Probably `{event.message.message}`

Comment: @furas In this case, I can lose the attachments that are inside this object. Is it possible to somehow re-create an object with the desired text inside? More precisely with its change?

Comment: I don't understand you.If you want to display message then use `{event.message.message}` in `send_message`. And if you have some attachements then you should send them also in `send_message`. Creating new `object` with new text makes no sense because it will be only local object and system will don't know it.

Answer (score 2):

The `event.message` object is a string, put it in a variable and add the text you want to it
Now put this variable to the `send_message` function

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=ID))
async def handler_new_message(event):
    try:
        message = event.message
        message += ": Message that I got from another channel"
        await client.send_message(ID, message)
        print('Сообщение:',event.message)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```